Example test doesn't work
I am in the basic-1 example (there is on the anchor repository) and when I run the test I get an error, I had to change the anchor version to 0.30.1 for it to run in order to get it from the /lang 
Solana version: 1.18.17
Anchor version: 0.30.1

Feel free to post an issue directly in the Anchor repo: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues
